# How can we "like" mulitple urls using fb like box

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How can I like multiple urls with a single click on fb-like button ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Spammers would abuse that like crazy.  You can have multiple like buttons on a page though, just set different href values for each thing you want people to like.